# Warning: Attempt to present modal controller on view controller while in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, uiviewcontroller

I know this might look like a duplicate but it's not because all of the questions/posts that I have found have not been related to mine, or not working.

Here is what I have. My root view controller is a HoldingViewController that has a left, main and right view controller. In my main view controller, in the view did load, I have a tutorial view controller that is launched if the user has not seen the tutorial yet. The problem I get when I dismiss the view controller is `Warning: Attempt to present <TutorialViewController: 0xade1780> on <HoldingViewController: 0xaaaa500> while a presentation is in progress!`

The call in the Main View Controller's view did load is:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    GRxTutorialViewController *grxTutorialViewController = [[GRxTutorialViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"GRxTutorialViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    grxTutorialViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:grxTutorialViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Inside the tutorial view I created a button to dismiss this modal view controller. It is:

```
-(void)skipIntro
{
    NSLog(@"Skip pressed");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I've also tried to put in the HidingViewController's viewDidLoad and it doesn't even display it and this message is logged:

`Warning: Attempt to present <TutorialViewController: 0xaac0ed0> on <HidingViewController: 0xaabe8d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve the problem or what my issue is and what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that at some point you set the hasSeenTutorial value to true and store it in the nsuserdefaults (before dismissing the tutorial)?

Comment: can you up vote the answer please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"]` in your AppDelegate and change your root view controller as follow:

```
GRxTutorialViewController *grxTutorialViewController = [[GRxTutorialViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"GRxTutorialViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

self.window.rootViewController = grxTutorialViewController;
```

In your Tutorial don't dismiss it. Present HoldingViewController instead.

Comment: How do I get it back to the regular application after the Tutorial has been dismissed?

Comment: I mentioned on the answer don't dismiss the tutorial. from the tutorial view present the HoldingViewController. in the AppDelegate your check the user default and you decide which is the root view controller.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a look and see if this works for me

Answer (score -1):

Launching tutorial view controller in HidingViewController's `viewDidAppear` method may help you

**Edit For More Details**

Just keeping one boolean value, you can avoid loop. If you want to show tutorial only once,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tutorialShouldDisplay = YES;
}



 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.tutorialShouldDisplay && ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"])
    {
        self.tutorialShouldDisplay = NO;
        /*
             should set NSUserDefaults properly for key @"hasSeenTutorial"
        */
        GRxTutorialViewController *grxTutorialViewController = [[GRxTutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GRxTutorialViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        grxTutorialViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentViewController:grxTutorialViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

As @hasan said you can do some modification on rootViewController in AppDelegate. However, I don't think is suitable for your structure.
Actually, there are many solutions exits, but you have to change structure. If you don't want to change your structure, this solution should work.

Comment: I just tried it, and it does not. And actually shows the MainViewController for a few seconds then shows the TutorialViewController, but I still get the warning message.

Comment: Accually, I did not answer correctly. It should be in HidingViewController's viewDidAppear method. Please could you try this?

Comment: are you sure that this still give you the same warning?

Comment: @hasan: this is the error message `Warning: Attempt to present <TutorialViewController: 0xaab39b0> on <HidingViewController: 0xaab2660> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: @caglar That worked! How do I get it to show up before the MainViewController? The MainViewController shows for a few seconds and then shows the tutorial view controller, I even have animation = NO.

Comment: @caglar Actually, this didn't work! Now I have a loop. If I hit the skip button, or dismiss the view controller, it goes away for a brief second but then reappears again. I have this inside the HidingViewController's viewDidAppear.

Comment: I edited the answer for more details.Please check it.

Comment: @caglar wouldn't it be better to have that as a static (by **that** I mean self.tutorialShouldDisplay). I think this would work.